# Для чего нужен указатель перед названием функции

Tags: c, функции, указатели

для чего нужен указатель перед `*replaceWord`:

```
char *replaceWord(const char *s, const char *oldW, 
                                 const char *newW)
```

Comment: Для чего и зачем он конкретно нужен - зависит от функции. Что там у вас творится внутри `replaceWord` нам отсюда не видно.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле это относится к возвращаемому значению, так наверное понятнее

```
char* replaceWord(const char *s, const char *oldW, const char *newW){
    return (char*) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: @AnT поправил :\

Answer (score 1):

Это всего лишь *возврашаемый тип* - `char*`, что говорит о том, что данная функция возвращает указатель на `char`.